# How do I move my champion while the nexus is exploding?

Tags: league-of-legends

Lots of games I'll see people move after/during the nexus explosion animation.

Whenever I try to move, or type, during this time, my champion remains motionless.
I have accidentally been able to move my champion, but I do not know what I did to cause it. It should be noted, that it appears that when I have seen champions move like this, it is only in one direction.

Is there a way that I can reliably move my champion at the end of the game?

Comment: I assume it'd be a queued command that your champion continues to execute as the nexus is destroyed. I'm not too sure if its the same in  LoL but in almost every RTS I've played you can hold shift to queue up multiple commands. Try clicking to attack the Nexus, then Shift-click somewhere else whilst attacking it to move there after the nexus is destroyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I've found to do  this is using an ability that has a decent channel time right before the nexus explodes, so the channeling goes into the time where everybody stops moving. While it's channeling, I right click somewhere (anywhere should work). I've found this works best with abilities like Fizz's E, or teleport.

Comment: I have been able to recreate this using this method several times, so it seems like this will work. I would prefer an easier method, but such a method may not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You continue to perform your previous command if you were untargetable at the moment that the game ended.  Essentially, when the nexus explodes, it hits all targetable champions with an effect that says "stop what you are doing, stand still, and don't do anything any more."

Fizz E and Zhonya's Hourglass are the two most common ways to avoid that effect, and allow your champion to continue with the last order afterwards.  I usually do this if possible, and order the champion to walk onto the enemy fountain.

I believe that Zed's ult and Guardian Angel and similar revival moves also work, but I have not tested them.